# How does Dart know when a program has finished in relation to asynchronous code

Tags: asynchronous, dart, event-handling, future

I've been learning about the event loop and asynchronous code execution in Dart. Here is how I understand it works:

- Dart runs the synchronous code in main first.
- Any completed futures are put on the event queue and get run in FIFO order.
- Any microtask events get handled before the next event in the event queue.

The part I'm missing is what about an uncompleted future? What if you have something like this:

```dart
final myFuture = Future<int>.delayed(
  Duration(seconds: 1),
  () => 42,
);
```

In that one second delay, say all the synchronous code, microtasks, and event queue tasks have completed. How does Dart know it shouldn't terminate the program? Is there a little holder somewhere for uncompleted futures?

I don't know if my title accurately reflects what I'm asking. Feel free it edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The life-time of a Dart program depends on where it runs.

Code running in a browser doesn't stop unless the page goes away. Web pages won't end like a script or application does.

So, what you are likely really asking is when a program run on the Dart VM stops. The short answer is: When there is nothing more to do (in the main isolate).

The program ends when the *main isolate* is done. That's the first isolate to run. If you start new isolates, they won't keep the program alive by themselves, so make sure to keep the main isolate alive until your program is done.

An isolate is done when there is nothing more to do, and there is no good way to receive instructions to do something more.
That means:

- There is no code running.
- The event and microtask queues are empty.
- There are no scheduled timers or outstanding I/O operations (you can think of these as being kept in separate internal work queues, and when they have a result ready, they trigger events in the main event queue. These queues also need to be empty for the program to be done).
- There are no open receive ports ([ReceivePort](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-isolate/ReceivePort-class.html), [RawReceivePort](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-isolate/RawReceivePort-class.html)).

That means that there is nothing to do, and no open communication channels to receive messages on.

The traditional way to keep an isolate alive, perhaps because the real computation is being done in a different isolate, is to create a `ReceivePort`, and then close it when everything else is done (which you'd probably notify them about by sending an event to that receive-port).